# Insert Objects into Vector when Class Has Constants

Tags: c++

Say I have a class that has only constants, since the values should never change.

```
struct Test {
    const std::string id;
    const int a;
    const double b;
};
```

Later on, I want to add objects into a vector, but I want the vector to be sorted by `b` from largest to smallest. I use insertion sort, since there will only ever be a small number (maybe 5).

```
std::vector<Test> values;

void addValue( const std::string &id, int a, double b ) {
    // Keep stockpiles sorted by weight (large to small)
    auto itr = values.begin();
    while ( itr != values.end() && itr->b > b ) ++itr;
    values.insert( itr, { id, a, b } );
    // end sort
}
```

Attempting the above, I get the following error while attempting to insert into the vector:

> error: object of type 'Test' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted

I would like to keep with using a `vector` for this problem; but I can't seem to find a way around the sorting issue. The only other option I could think of was to effectively recreate the `vector` constantly. Alternatively, using a `multi-set` or similar, then once all values are added, I could dump into an array.

Is there a way around this limitation, still using a `vector` and not making everything non-const? Or will I be forced to change my structure, or move away into a temporary object first?

Edit: Also trying to avoid the use of pointers

Comment: Do you need `std::vector`? If you use `std::set`, it will keep elements sorted for you automatically and does not need to assign them.

Comment: Sorting a vector requires swapping, swapping requires modifying values. You have enumerated all of your possibilities that do not involve removing the members' constness.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica, I use a vector for performance reasons. The initial building of the `vector` is only done once; however, looping over all its elements is done millions of times. In my experience, `set`s have very poor performance (relatively) for iterating over its elements.

Comment: @ChrisMM Then, build a `set` first and copy its (sorted) elements into a `vector`. This should not require their assignment. Something as `std::vector<Test> values(set.begin(),set.end());`.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica That is what I was leaning toward, but I was wondering if there's a way by just using the `vector`. From what I've seen, I'm guessing not.

Comment: @ChrisMM Do you really need your members to be const?  With this definition, your class violates the requirements of CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible.

Comment: @ChrisMM you should seek a way to reduce amount of iterations. What you do is called micro-optimizations, which in long term do not provide any performance benefits, while making code less clean, which should always be a priority. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" D.E. Knuth

Comment: @ElvisOric it's more to prevent accidental modification of data.

Comment: @doc, I've done all the optimizations I can to reduce the number of calls to functions which will use these. The application is memory bound, so using "memory friendly" structures is much better for my purposes.

Comment: Use a struct with non-const members, then use const iterators to access `std::vector`'s elements.

Comment: @ChrisMM OK, so you simply can not do this in the way you presented it to us. But this is not a limitation. You could hack it by providing custom copy/move constructor and assignment operators (with const_cast), but it's pointless. Either use non-const members as people point our or use some another solution like temporary structure.

Comment: @doc, I guess my question was more of "is it possible", or do I need to use one of the other methods (multi-set, etc.). I've used the set solution for now. Will try to find a better solution in the future, when doing our next re-write.

Comment: @ChrisMM as I pointed out it is possible if you provide custom copy/move ctor and assignment operator. But it would be an abuse of a language, because by using const members you've actually said that you don't want them to be modified and then you want to use a structure, which needs to modify elements as part of its normal operation. Problem is not whether it's possible, but what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ChrisMM you could even make `std::vector` a friend class and grant access to custom ctors and operators only to `std::vector` if you'd really wanted to prevent modification from other places.

Comment: @doc, I like that idea of making vector a friend. I tried it out, but the I get an error about not being able to access the `operator=` since it is private. The copies are all done outside of the vector class, and are done in an `xutility` header.

Comment: @ChrisMM and thank God, because it was a terrible idea.

Comment: @ChrisMM if you really want to go with this approach, encapsulate your data in Test class, provide ctor and you are ready.

Comment: I'll stick with the temporary `set` until all elements are added.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, sorting requires moving around elements in your vector. And moving around elements generally requires move-assignment, which generally requires mutation of elements…

There is one way out of this dillema: instead of assigning a new value to the existing object, create a new object with the new value on top of the existing one. One can do so by defining a copy/move constructor like, e.g.:

```cpp
    Test& operator =(Test&& other)
    {
        this->~Test();
        return *new (this) Test(std::move(other));
    }
```

There is just one problem with this: via [[basic.life]/8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8.3), we're not allowed to use any existing pointer or reference to the original object, or even just the name of the original object after such an assignment. You would always have to use the result of the assignment (the return value of placement-new) or a [laundered pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) as the sole means of accessing the object going forward. Since it is not specified how `std::sort` operates exactly, we cannoy rely on it doing so.

What we *could* to is build a wrapper like this (noexcept ommited for readability):

```cpp
template <typename T>
class const_element
{
    T value;

    const T& laundered_value() const { return *std::launder(&value); }
    T& laundered_value() { return *std::launder(&value); }

public:
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit const_element(Args&&... args) : value { std::forward<Args>(args)... } {}

    const_element(const const_element& e) : value(e.laundered_value()) {}
    const_element(const_element&& e) : value(std::move(e.laundered_value())) {}

    const_element& operator =(const const_element& e)
    {
        laundered_value().~T();
        new (&value) T(e.laundered_value());
        return *this;
    }

    const_element& operator =(const_element&& e)
    {
        laundered_value().~T();
        new (&value) T(std::move(e.laundered_value()));
        return *this;
    }

    ~const_element()
    {
        laundered_value().~T();
    }

    operator const T&() const { return laundered_value(); }
    operator T&() { return laundered_value(); }

    friend bool operator <(const_element& a, const_element& b)
    {
        return a.laundered_value() < b.laundered_value();
    }
};
```

What this does is wrap an object of some type `T`, implement copy and move assignment in the way described above, and make sure that any access to the current value always goes through a laundered pointer.

Then we can just do

```cpp
    std::vector<const_element<Test>> values;
    values.emplace_back("b", 1, 0.0);
    values.emplace_back("a", 0, 0.0);
    values.emplace_back("c", 2, 0.0);

    std::sort(begin(values), end(values));
```

working example [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ1QBXYsg4ByKQGY8tZK2VYA1OO0BhZQTytCATzPZxABgCCOvQaOZTF2pgB3Rxd3SV19QxMzcwUCYj1gYLcPCO9fcwA3TGQiYiTQ8K8oizZgEkIEAFt8lKKfaLxUWOJMZmrtJ2Su12blHOMAFUxY0wB2WTdjKeM0WhHY9BAQZoTjPHQzCddpmboRvQJjZk2QndmR9BUAI3ZjK5Pk0YARB/c3PVt/O9RUVmNUAAOmGIzFy6QgQ1iUgAbEdSINhgQYXcAJQhcTjU7TFoEVS0I4AOmY6TuRNeGJe3Q%2Beh8CyWTTirWqklhgOBoJI6WiEDpIAZLTayJUBHh50OkKRLOMBDRjy2OxxeP%2BVi5FmlBPWqvMpkkknhUkkWvVxOi0R1evNRoIBPu2i2FPR3QImEqAOEzvSBDsQNobR8A3yBmYCgUuzmBAA%2Bph2JVMPR0ZjJtMBsYMmxlJhyUmpmLBsjhMpaFgWugI2nDJgICiwyNaKhMAAPdQAw4Y6TGRXEfEAKl5BaLwIgMPLGbRdrGlO2yfzzELxcwpZHlerdcbzdb4w7mFxXeMvYIixA/eLQ5ZS7H7Yd3QByhueGQICxU2drvd9QsXp9foJP%2BMrmIwAKPkOyNm696EDWkbRi6cYEBA/6ATCMI/gSRwAQoK71k2mAthAq7YbhKZtsYvI0MQATMMQGwWAhQEdBAlGASiKETii1YgKm6b1JupEkBRVHRLRjgMehzG/hSYyyM8jpTjmexQTGsEQLmYpRop8ZSpgmFrjhcH4euEIQJgBLHsCC5llxVZsexnEVkZJmzgOJYWXZbGSVesmQWpMH0Mp8nebGGnQsiWnGPpul4VhBkDDyB5LJUqBZPZpnOUuVnWcYHFpbyCVJcZKXmWlGVth5T5edBgWSqyQIgmCZhPH54blepVXGKF4W4R1cExfljnzoulnWbKnkldmOzGAVA2uQSAB%2BMUXmVOz%2BAExintC56DMlfVmVNGZWa843YtuSrdgQCB4HR8rTKVY2qRVsFCjVHLEL4DV3S1SGadpBF6VFEUxTliWVr1c47S5e1DcNOyjZ5OyTeDy6zfNB2HWFgSrcOXHVgDcUgLlwMOaDqWDWxKOHZ2PZnRdZMTjJOwze9Plwd9BldRA8NFUj6VlTDqMTdtxPTXNVY0zdnlsrVnK5gGLJVpBYV/S2klbju%2BIc4Nmy02NEvPXmsss7pysU/zROFRr45izsVDxHG6DfL8/xPXVFiNbEAUPVKzCiv591BaiCs6Z1itwcwhNOWbrkklcYf9Qj3NjbzqPG6H6uR2a0epxDovSY8Lx2jJIQHMYlTMHoItymVvJZDkJDRIzlXRBKwQdLZGaXWVS4KASLpusw6gRlcfcANanpI9y6vCnDws4BLOAtY2d93r595gA/D6PxwT8YzjT7P8%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%2BSAbgoxwWSG4Ai5wWytmjFGJILZ3BcHQlZRoeZKLDU4Ildi%2BVkh2Wor9Zi75n8shuMaEQ7gQA%3D%3D)

All that being said, I would recommend to just not do this. If you want an object that cannot be modified, simply use a `const T` rather than a `T` that solely consists of const members. You cannot have a vector of `const T`. But you can have a vector of `T` and then just pass around a reference to a const vector or a range of const elements…

Answer (score -1):

You could store pointers in the vector. Of course, you would also need to clean everything up. Example at http://cpp.sh/3h7dr

```
std::vector<Test*> values;

void addValue( const std::string &id, int a, double b ) {
    // Keep stockpiles sorted by weight (large to small)
    auto itr = values.begin();
    while ( itr != values.end() && ((*itr)->b > b) ) ++itr;
    Test* t = new Test{id,a,b};
    values.insert( itr, t );
    // end sort
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to move away from using pointers. I have done this many times in other parts of the code, but now I am trying to reduce the use of pointers where they are not strictly needed.

Comment: I understand, maybe make an explicit statement in your question that you don't want to store pointers.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have. I've edited it so it does now.